# The right post variable

Tags: php

I have a submit buttom like this:

```
<?php
   echo "<form id='abottom' method='post'>
         <button name='".$row3[$ww]."' id='".$row3[$ww]."' type='button'>More Details</button>
         <input type='hidden' name='action' value='".$row3[$ww]."' />
         </form>";
?>
```

and ids are working right of the buttons of the table rows (by [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29)). But when I want to output `$_POST` in a query `while` loop, then no one of those works for me:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST[$row3[$ww]]." <br />";
    echo $_POST['$row3[$ww]']." <br />";
    echo $_POST[$row3['$ww']]." <br />";
    echo $_POST["$row3[$ww]"]." <br />";
    echo $_POST[$row3["$ww"]]." <br />";
    echo $_POST[$row3['".$ww."']]." <br />";
?>
```

Which one will be the right? Those above didn't work for me.

```
  $row3 // is a fetch result of sql3
  $ww // is table rows name on which one is selected
```

Raw HTML output example:

```
<form name ='dets' method='POST'>
    <input class = 'showt' name ='6' id ='6' type='button' value= 'More Details'></input>
    <input type='hidden' name='data' value='6' />
    <noscript><input type='submit' value='Submit'></noscript>
</form>
```

Comment: What's a typical value for `$row3[$ww]`?

Comment: typical value is (1 , or 2 , or ,,, )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much better for debugging and finding the correct variable would be to use

```
<?php
    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($_REQUEST);
    echo '</pre>';
```

to see which variables arrive at your script.

---

**Update:**

I think, what you need is:

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $row3[$ww]; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="More Details"/>
</form>

<?php
    echo $_POST['data']];
```

And if you have several values in `$row3` then add extra forms like this:

```
<form method="post">
    Second Data
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $row4[$ww]; ?>"/>
    <input type="submit" value="More Details"/>
</form>
```

Always keep the name of the hidden input the same (`data`)!

Comment: That's a bit useless without knowing what his script is outputting in the first place.

Comment: i will post it here the dump ?

Comment: this the dump i get from your code   `array(6) {
  ["menucompare"]=>
  string(7) "turning"
  ["hidevalue"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["ff6117daf822c96a098a447832bd9ba3"]=>
  string(26) "73s7scfacm6v338df9fdriq6i0"
  ["option"]=>
  string(8) "com_jumi"
  ["Itemid"]=>
  string(3) "186"
  ["fileid"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}`

Comment: I cleaned up your script above please try again.

Comment: but my button was working good with the ids no problem , im wondering for those `$_POST` which didnt

Answer (score 0):

Your button has `type="button"`. This should be `type="submit"` or it won't submit the form it is in.

Your [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) code should look like this:

```
<?php
    echo "<form id='abottom' method='post'>
          <button name='".$row3[$ww]."' id='".$row3[$ww]."' type='submit'>More Details</button>
          <input type='hidden' name='action' value='".$row3[$ww]."' />
          </form>";
?>
```